# Golang ReverseProxy with Iris-Go framework

Tags: go, reverse-proxy, go-iris

Anybody able to wire Golang's ReverseProxy functionality with Iris-Go web framework. I couldnt make it working. I am able to wire it with regular net/http.

```
func MultiHostReverseProxy(targets map[string]utils.Service) *httputil.ReverseProxy {
    r := regexp.MustCompile(`\/proxy/(?P<Service>[a-zA-Z_-]*)(?P<Path>\/.*)`)
    director := func(req *http.Request) {
        if strings.HasPrefix(req.URL.Path, "/proxy/") {
            temp := r.FindStringSubmatch(req.URL.Path);
            if (len(temp) > 1) {
                system := temp[1]
                if val, ok := targets[system]; ok {
                    s := val.Host + ":" + val.Port
                    req.URL.Scheme = val.Scheme
                    req.URL.Host = s
                    req.URL.Path = temp[2]

                    if enc, ok := GetAxleHeader(req.Header); ok {
                        dec := utils.Decrypt(KEY, enc)
                        req.Header.Set(val.AuthHeader, dec)
                        req.Header.Set(AXLE_HEADER, "")
                    } else {
                        token, nq := utils.FindAxleToken(req.URL.RawQuery);
                        fmt.Printf("%s -> token : %s    newQuery: %s\n", req.URL.RawQuery, token, nq);
                        if token != "" {
                            req.URL.RawQuery = nq
                            dec := utils.Decrypt(KEY, token)
                            req.Header.Set(val.AuthHeader, dec)
                            req.Header.Set(AXLE_HEADER, "")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return &httputil.ReverseProxy{Director: director}
}
```

How can I use this ReverseProxy object with iris framework;

Comment: I don't understand why anyone uses iris http://www.florinpatan.ro/2016/10/why-you-should-not-use-iris-for-your-go.html?m=1

Comment: you can't use the httputil reverse proxy, because iris doesn't use the std lib net/http package.

Comment: @JimB After version 5, Iris is built on top of net/http to complete its HTTP/2 features.

Answer (score 0):

After searching and posting at Iris i got this example in iris sources. May be helpful for others

https://github.com/kataras/iris/blob/master/http.go#L1412

Comment: Link is dead unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

With iris you have two options, make a proxy server and run it:

```
import "github.com/kataras/iris/core/host"
[...]
target, _ := url.Parse("https://example.com")
go host.NewProxy("example.com:80", target).ListenAndServe()
// this will proxy all http://example.com to https://example.com
// you can use that proxy as you like.
```

create a new proxy handler and use it anywhere you like:

```
import "github.com/kataras/iris/core/host"
[...]
target, _ := url.Parse("https://example.com")
proxy := host.ProxyHandler(target)
http.ListenAndServe("example.com:80", proxy)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do dynamic proxying, means, i cant configure my proxy to a constant third server, rather its on the incoming requests Header(say X-Forward-To).. So that request i should forward to the corresponding server mentioned there...

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of the below might be what you are looking for.

(omitting app boilerplate)

```
remote, err := url.Parse("http://google.com")
proxyHandler := func(p *httputil.ReverseProxy) func(ctx iris.Context) {
    return func(ctx iris.Context) {
        r := ctx.Request()
        w := ctx.ResponseWriter()
        // log.Println(r.URL)
        r.Host = remote.Host
        r.URL.Path = ctx.Params().Get("p")
        w.Header().Set("X-Some", "Thing")
        p.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    }
}

proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(remote)
proxy.Transport = &http.Transport{
    TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: false},
}

app.Any("/proxy/{p:path}", proxyHandler(proxy))
```

Be careful not to expose your secret values from `Request` while proxying. Also this does not handle trailing or no trailing slashes. So you cannot visit `google.com`, but you can visit `google.com/something`. Also be sure to know where you are proxying to. The above does not forbid redirects. E.g. `google.com/about` will eventually have your client leaving your host.